# How to make equal space between boxes in one row via CSS

Tags: css

I have a requirement that there are 4 boxes in one row.

1. the boxes have fixed width and height
2. but the width of the row will change by screen size.
3. the first box should be aligned to the left border of the row
4. last box aligned to right border.
5. Also the space between any two boxes should be equal.

Is there a pure CSS way to make that happen? Here is the [`jsfiddle code`](http://jsfiddle.net/chennanfei/NUsZY/1/).

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class ="col">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class ="col">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class ="col">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class ="col">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 400px; /* it changes by screen size actually */
    padding: 5px;
}
.row:before, .row:after {
    content: "";
}
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
.box {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.col:first-child .box {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.col:last-child .box {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `text-align:justify` on the container, this way it will work no matter how many elements you have in your div (you don't have to work out % widths for each list item

### Updated CSS

```
.row {
    text-align: justify;
    min-width: 412px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 80%; /* it changes by screen size actually */
    height: 90px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.row:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.col {
    display: inline-block;
}
.box {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/avrLX/2/)**

Comment: I like this one. It works for me and its compatibility is better. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [css3 flex boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) which is [supported](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) in modern browsers.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NUsZY/4/)

more about flex boxes @ [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks! it works, however the CSS properties look a little new to  browsers.

Comment: @it works in all major browsers except ie9. note that `flex` has the ability to shrink if the browser window is too small. the accepted answer creates scrollbar. not sure which is the behavior required for you though.

Comment: I can set 'hidden' overflow and fixed height to the class 'row', that would satisfy my need then

Answer (score 0):

Why not use flexbox ?

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/4dgaurav/pen/cFClI)**

css

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between; /* this make the end divs at sides and equal space between other divs */
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;

  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

html

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">4</div>
</div>
```

[Read here for more detail on flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

you simply have to remove the padding attribute from the following

```
.row {
display: table;
border: 1px solid green;
width: 400px; /* it changes by screen size actually */
/*padding: 5px;*/
}
```

[here is the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/NUsZY/6/)

Let me know if this was helpful or if you have anymore queries.